# Image overlay table in html newsletter

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

I am making a HTML newsletter and keep running into this problem. The image at the top for some reason ignores the margin and gives an ugly white line.

While this site says that email clients should accept margin's: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit: new and cleaner code, but still same problem! I have no idea how to get that damn thing down. =/ (also my left border is gone now, and I don't know why)**

[image]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="811px" style="border:0px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
            <td width="150px" VALIGN=TOP style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">Nieuwsbrief #<?php echo $nr; ?></td>
            <td width="500px" style="vertical-align: bottom;"><img src="http://pietrow.net/newsletter/images/lad_wide.png" style="z-index:-1;"></img></td>
            <td width="150px" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;" >Datum: <?php echo $datum; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000; border-top: 0px" width="811px">
            <td width="270px"><center><a href="http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~kaiser/">Website</a></center></td>
            <td width="271px"><center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LADKaiser">Facebook</a></center></td>
            <td width="270px"><center><a href="mailto:kaiser@strw.leidenuniv.nl">Contact</a></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border:0px; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000;" width="811px">
            <td colspan="3" width="811px"><center><a href="#ENTOP">**ENGLISH VERSION BELOW**</a></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
            <td style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 0px;" colspan="3" width="811px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember with HTML emails you need to go very much 'old-school' as the email clients that render them are even more archaic than even old versions of IE.
Therefore, try to remember back to the days before DIVs and lovely CSS layouts, back to the days when tables were for layout...

Try adding:

```
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

to your table declaration then consider putting your content in a table *within* the main table as opposed to two tables stacked on top of one another. Or, if you can, rationalise the three columns and create one single table.

Comment: It does not work. :P THe problem I had with putting everything in one table is that the top box needs to be white and borderless, while the stuff below it is gray and has borders. (is there a way to do this?)

Comment: Apply inline styles to the table cells you want with borders/backgrounds. This is a long winded way of doing it but that's the problem with HTML emails.

Comment: So the transparent table wraps around the rest? I'll try that

Comment: Did some updates (see main post) but still same problem and now the left border is gone O.o)

Comment: HTML emails are painful !
I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WeB3X/
I added 'display: block;' to the image and that pulls it down into the correct place.
Also, on the fiddle the borders are displayed correctly so maybe some peculiarity of your display is hiding them ?

Comment: I've fixed the borders but the image is still broken (even in the fiddle :P)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WeB3X/1/ did a dirty fix by putting background to that color and giving the logo white. (but moving it down that tiny bit would be great:P)

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and if you apply 'display: block' to the img, that fixes it (at least in FireFox)

Answer (score 1):

You need `display:block;` on your image. Here is an example of how all images should look in html email:

```
<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="" width="" height="" alt="">
```

Some additional notes:

- You don't need `<center>`, use `<td align="center">` instead.
- You shouldn't use `px` in the `width=""` declarations. Example: `width="150"`
- Declare background color only in a table or table cell using bgcolor method. Example: `bgcolor="#DBDBDB"`

Comment: Also, if that image is clickable, be sure to include <img src="" border="0" />

Comment: @RLacorne I've never found the need for the `border="0"` in a hyperlinked image tag - what client have you found to be the inspiration for that?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook 2002 software on Windows XP will display a 2-3px blue link border if border="0" is not included. While it my seem that no one uses this software anymore, including border="0" is a good habit to have, as some persons still live in the past when it comes to computers. :)

Comment: Maybe it's due to the version of Windows too.